# MTL4 apply unary operator (e.g. abs()) elementwise to dense_vector<double>

Tags: c++, vector, unary-operator

I want to apply a unary operator, particualrly abs(), elementwise to a dense_vector< double>.

Is there a native variant to do this (rather than building manually a loop)? If so, I would need a brief explanation of the concept.

I browsed in the [MTL4 Entire Manual](http://www.simunova.com/node/148) and couldn't figure out, how to do it. It seems that I, somehow, have to define a corresponding functor. Is it mtl::sfunctor::abs? If so, how do I apply it to a vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick glance through [source of `dense_vector`](http://www.simunova.com/docs/mtl4/html/dense__vector_8hpp_source.html), it seems like a standard conformant container. Therefore, this should work:

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(),
    static_cast<double(*)(double)>(&std::abs));
```

Comment: Indeed, that worked. Many thanks. Can you name the lines that led you to that conclusion? What do you think about the computational complexity from a practical point of view? Does it make a difference compared to a standard loop?

Comment: The container's got iterators and that ought to be enough for algorithms to work with it. It's idiomatic C++. There's a O(n) loop under the hood, so a normal loop would be just as efficient, but using algorithms makes the intent clearer (and perhaps lets the compiler do better optimizations).